# How to use sed or awk to process the content of a specified column?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have such data in text.

```
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 K:N　
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631(Peter) 1:N　
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 1:N　
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 2208(Lucy) 2:C
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 2208 K:C
2017-08-07 189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 99999(Kate) 2:C
2017-08-07 189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 631(Peter) 2:C
2017-08-07 189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 631(Peter) 2:C
2017-08-07 733 AA3(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 99999(Kate) T:U　
2017-08-07 733 AA3(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 99999(Kate) 3:U
```

There are 6 columns in this text.Use space to separate each column of data.

I want to deal with the 5th column of data.

Some data contains names in the 5th column. There are more parentheses outside the data containing names. There are only numbers in the columns without names. This number is the employee number. I just want to take out the numbers in the 5th column, not name. I want this effect.

```
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 K:N　
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 1:N　
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 1:N　
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 2208 2:C
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 2208 K:C
2017-08-07 189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 99999 2:C
2017-08-07 189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 631 2:C
2017-08-07 189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 631 2:C
2017-08-07 733 AA3(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 99999 T:U　
2017-08-07 733 AA3(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 99999 3:U
```

I use this command to process data.

> ```
> cat mytextfile|sed 's/(/ /g' > resultfile
> ```

But the 3rd column has also been modified, because the 3rd column also contains parentheses. In fact, I just want to process the 5th column.

What should I do with sed or awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using sed (simple)

To remove all parens that contain only letters, try:

```
$ sed 's/([[:alpha:]]*)//' myfile
2017-08-07　733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 K:N　
2017-08-07　733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 1:N　
2017-08-07　733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 1:N　
2017-08-07　733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 2208 2:C
2017-08-07　733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 2208 K:C
2017-08-07　189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 99999 2:C
2017-08-07　189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 631 2:C
2017-08-07　189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 631 2:C
2017-08-07　733 AA3(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 99999 T:U　
2017-08-07　733 AA3(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 99999 3:U
```

`([[:alpha:]]*)` matches `(` followed by zero or more alphabetic characters followed by `)`.  `s/([[:alpha:]]*)//` locates those characters and replaces them with an empty string.

#### Using sed (improved)

This removes parenthesized expressions of alphabetic characters from the fifth field and only the fifth field:

```
$ sed -E 's/(([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4}[^[:space:]]*)\([[:alpha:]]*\)/\1/' myfile
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 K:N
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 1:N
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 1:N
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 2208 2:C
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 2208 K:C
2017-08-07 189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 99999 2:C
2017-08-07 189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 631 2:C
2017-08-07 189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 631 2:C
2017-08-07 733 AA3(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 99999 T:U
2017-08-07 733 AA3(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 99999 3:U
```

#### Using awk

To remove any parenthesized expression in the fifth field:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]]+' '{gsub(/\(.*\)/, "", $5)} 1' myfile
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 K:N
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 1:N
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 1:N
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 2208 2:C
2017-08-07 733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 2208 K:C
2017-08-07 189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 99999 2:C
2017-08-07 189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 631 2:C
2017-08-07 189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 631 2:C
2017-08-07 733 AA3(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 99999 T:U
2017-08-07 733 AA3(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 99999 3:U
```

How it works:

1. `-F'[[:space:]]+'`

   This tells awk to use any sequence of unicode-recognized whitespace as the field separator.  (The default is only to recognize sequences of blank, tab, and newline as field separators.)
2. `gsub(/\(.*\)/, "", $5)`

   This looks in the fifth field, `$5`, for any parenthesized expression, `\(.*\)`, and replaces it with the empty string `""`.
3. `1`

   This is shorthand which tells awk to print the line.

Comment: A direct copy of the file shows the wide-space between `$1` and `$2` is actually a UTF-8 `"IDEO­GRAPHIC SPACE"` (`e3 80 80`) and there are a few sprinkled as line endings. So if the OP has any issues -- that may be the cause...

Comment: ....and why I was leaning towards using `$(NF-1)` instead of `$5` so it'd work either way. btw nit-pick - you just want to do 1 substitution so you should be using `sub()` rather than `gsub()`.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidC.Rankin, for that observation.  This shouldn't affect the `sed` solutions since `[:space:]` will match any unicode-recognized whitespace.   Getting the right behavior with awk is more subtle.

Comment: Rafael, were you aware of the use of `IDEO­GRAPHIC SPACE (e3 80 80)` in your files?  Is that supposed to be there or were they added in the posting process?  Are they supposed to be there?  Are they consistently between the first and second fields?  I'm asking because, as @EdMorton points out, there are some subtleties when dealing with these characters with the awk solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your example's specific case, the user names follow only digits, which is different than in column 3, where the IP address in parentheses follows letters and digits. You can leverage this to your advantage:

```
$ sed 's/\( [0-9][0-9]*\)([^)]*)/\1/g' mytextfile 
2017-08-07　733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 K:N　
2017-08-07　733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 1:N　
2017-08-07　733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 631 1:N　
2017-08-07　733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 2208 2:C
2017-08-07　733 AA1(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 2208 K:C
2017-08-07　189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 99999 2:C
2017-08-07　189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 631 2:C
2017-08-07　189 AA2(10.7.4.54) AllUsers 631 2:C
2017-08-07　733 AA3(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 99999 T:U　
2017-08-07　733 AA3(10.7.21.51) AllUsers 99999 3:U
```

That `sed` line says to capture a space followed by one or more numbers, followed by parentheses with anything inside, replacing all of that with the value captured.